# duplicate div inside the one class then remove the duplicate one

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one div

```
<div class='complete_status'>Upload Complete</div>
```

which could contain the

```
 <div class='complete_status'><div class="test">test test</div></div>
```

i want if

```
<div class='complete_status'><div class="test">test test</div><div class="test">test test</div></div>
```

"comlete_status" have div inside it "test" more then one.then remove the other div which have name "test"

**a minor update here :
 i have 20 div with class name ".complete_status" i want this according to multiple divs
every div should have only one class"test"**

Comment: It would probably be way more elegant to directly output the correct HTML instead of cleaning up afterwards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **[`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)** the status DIV before appending new status value.

```
$('.complete_status').empty().append('<div class="test">Test</div>');
```

Answer (score 4):

Target the `.test` elements inside `.complete_status`, and remove any with an index greater than 0

```
$('.complete_status .test:gt(0)').remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7JHTD/)

or to remove all children but the first child in multiple parents

```
$('.complete_status .test:not(:first-child)').remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7JHTD/1/)

Comment: I think `$('.complete_status .test').slice(1).remove();` will be better

Comment: @ArunPJohny - it's probably a little faster, but just keeping it in the selector looks better to me, and unless there are millions of .complete_status elements there won't be a noticeable difference

Comment: its looks good if what happen if i have 20 div with class name ".complete_status" i want this according to multiple divs

Comment: @SachinRawal - added a solution for that which doesn't require you to reset all content in the parents (which seems like a horrible idea to me)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.complete_status .test').slice(1).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KL727/1/

---

For multiple instances of **div.complete_status**:

```
$('.complete_status').each(function() {
  $('.test', this).slice(1).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> if($('.test').after())
>
> ```
>    $('.test').after().remove()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".test").length > 1)
{
   $("div.test:not(:first)").remove();
}
```

This checks if there are more than one elements with class *test* and removes all except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.complete_status').html($('.complete_status .test').first().html());
```

and if you have others nodes that you want to keep inside your parent node :

```
    var p = $('.complete_status .test');
    var f = p.first();
    p.remove();
    $('.complete_status').html(f.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ele = $('.complete_status > .test').slice(1);
$('.complete_status').text('').append(ele);
```